# Install npcap silently without npcap OEM Edition

Tags: networking, installation, npcap

Is there a way to silently install the npcap driver without the OEM Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways of doing that without the OEM version, but they are minimally unethical, if not outright illegal.

My organization is in the process of purchasing the OEM version.  The pricing structure varies with the size of the organization and how it is ultimately used.  I would recommend contacting the Nmap folks to see.

Comment: There should be a way to silently install it with nmap (but there isn't?), since there's unlimited distribution with nmap.

Answer (score 0):

you can use version 0.96,the version is last allow free silent installation